# Can I send an array by jquery.getJSON?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, getjson

I have this jquery code:

```
$(".cashOutButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var sendArray=[{'value': '123', 'type': 'Buy_Order_ID'},
                    {'value': '44.20', 'type': 'Set_Price'},
                    {'value': 'John', 'type': 'seller_Name'},
                    {'value': 'S', 'type': 'Sell_Type'}
                    ];

    var sendData = {'sendArray': sendArray};

    $.getJSON('addToSession.php',sendData,function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });        

})
```

and this php code - addToSession.php (it's just to test if it's working, the final code will be different):

```
<?php
print_r($_GET['sendArray']);
?>
```

It doesn't work. Nothing comes back. My question is, can I send an array of objects to $.getJSON? What other solutions are there to send arrays? It doesn't have to be array of objects, it could be array of arrays, if that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, and this is returning the data you expect. You can test this by looking at the response in the Net tab of your browser's developer tools.

It isn't being displayed in `console.log` because `getJSON` requires that the response it gets is JSON and you are responding something that claims to be an HTML document (the default for PHP) but which contains the output of `print_r` (which isn't valid HTML or JSON).

Send JSON back and it will work:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($_GET['sendArray']);
?>
```

Comment: it didn't work. It drives me crazy. I didn't get your first sentence. What is the best way to test this? Where is Net Tab?

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5823880/use-your-browsers-developer-tools-to-learn-new-html-css-and-javascript-techniques shows how to open the developer tools. I don't understand why you are writing code with console.log if you can't find them though.

Comment: And it does work: http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/24648292/ (you'll need the developer tools open to see the JS console to see the output of console.log)

Comment: It can't work, because he is sending undefined values in get request.

Comment: I found the Net tab, and it shows as expected under Response. Thanks for telling me about it. I didn't know there was a way to see this. However, why I can't get it to display in console.log is a mystery to me. I am using developer tools, I just never noticed the Net tab or I didn't know what it was for. Console tab I use frequently.

Comment: @Choinek — There are no undefined values in the GET request. Look at the Net tab on the live example I linked to. You can see the URL, there is nothing undefined in it.

Comment: Choinek, can you explain? I think I got it to work. Why do you think it could not work?

Comment: @user2395238 — As I said, the only thing stopping it showing up in the console was that you were forcing the browser to parse the results of `print_r` as JSON. Change the PHP to the code in this answer and it works.

Comment: @Quentin - thanks for your help. I got it to work. I had a typo.

Answer (score -1):

In this case you should use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ instead.

JQuery.getJSON, as name of method says should be used to GET JSON data, and not send it. Thats because your array is converted to GET, and it generate json request like

**addToSession.php?undefined=123&undefined=44.20&undefined=John&undefined=S**.

To send JSON data use jQuery.post with "json" dataType.

```
$.post( "addToSession.php", sendData, function( data ) {
  console.log( data);
}, "json");
```

And your array should be in final like:

```
{sendData: [ {'value': '123', 'type': 'Buy_Order_ID'},
         {'value': '44.20', 'type': 'Set_Price'},
         {'value': 'John', 'type': 'seller_Name'},
         {'value': 'S', 'type': 'Sell_Type'}
]}
```

Comment: Adding `"json"` as the third argument of `$.post` tells jQuery to parse the response as JSON, not to send JSON. It will still use the form url encoding format to send the data.

Comment: re edit: Arrays don't have a `serialize` property, so now you are sending the string `undefined`.

Comment: Yup, that's correct i fixed it. I tested this one and it is working right now.

Comment: Oh, and you are wrong about the original code generating `undefined=123&undefined=44.20&undefined=John&undefined=S`. The code in the question is using `{'sendArray': sendArray}`, not `sendArray` as the second argument to `getJSON`.

Comment: It's not problem, because author has access to code and he can change it to $_POST? :P There's no point to send array data using get request method.

Comment: That would solve the third problem I mentioned, but not the first. The PHP is still sending a document claiming to be `text/html` with the output of a `print_r` statement as the value and you are forcing jQuery to parse it as JSON. It isn't JSON. That won't work.

Comment: Why is there "no point to send array data using get request method"? The method you choose should be based on what is done with the data, not on what the data is. It is perfectly valid to use GET for this type of thing.

Comment: After your latest edit  you have made the code pretty much identical to the original code except you are using POST instead of GET. That still won't help.

Comment: Sorry dude but nope, sending gets like sendArray%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=123&sendArray%5B0%5D%5Btype%5D=Buy_Order_ID&sendArray%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=44.20... is not good. What if he must send 100 elements in future? Many servers have GET limitations...

Comment: URL length limits can be an issue, but there is nothing in the question that suggests the array is of arbitrary length.

Comment: Choinek, I can use $.postJSON, it doesn't really matter. The number of elements would never be that long, so $.getJSON is ok too. Quentin's answer was correct though. Because the problem I had was it was not showing in console.log. And that was caused by incorrect using of print_r